# Translation errors during database migration using SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration, oracle12c

I am trying to migrate a SQL Server 2012 database to Oracle 12c (R2) using SQL Developer. Though I am able to migrate few objects but not all and getting the following errors in MIGRLOG table.

**SEVERITY**   **LOGTEXT**

900          Translation limitation 'OBJECT_ID' encountered on Stored Procedure..

1000         Failed To Convert Stored Procedure xx No oracle.dbtools.metadata.persistence.MdStoredProgram found with id = 485,151

My questions are

1. What are the various severity levels that could exist in SEVERITY column of MIGRLOG table and what levels should be considered as migration errors?
2. Is there is any guideline document available to fix translation errors (ex:Translation limitation 'OBJECT_ID')

Answer (score 1):

Anytime there is a translation limitation, it will either fail to translate the procedure and report this or, it will report this, and comment out the unsupported item.

You could use the translation scratch editor off the tools > migration menu to paste in your stored procedure and test translate it.  If it fails with errors, comment out the item it is raising and try again.  It should translate and you'll know that you need to modify your code to make the item that didnt translate correct in the new code.